# Show that (c) $S=T^{-1}.$, (d)$\Vert S_{n}-T^{-1}\Vert\leq \frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{1-\lambda}.$, (e) $S_{n+1}=I+(I-T)S_{n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

For the following question, **I need just hint not a whole solutions**. As you see I have solved the first two parts.

> **The Problem**: Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T : X \to X$ be linear with $\Vert I −T\Vert =
> \lambda < 1.$ Let $S_n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}(I-T)^{j}.$ Show that
>
> (a) T is one to one. (**I have solved**)
>
> (b) The sequence $\{S_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is convergent in $\mathcal{B}(X).$ (**I have solved**)
>
> (c) Let $S=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}S_{n}.$ Show that $S=T^{-1}.$
>
> (d) $\Vert S_{n}-T^{-1}\Vert\leq \frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{1-\lambda}.$
>
> (e) $S_{n+1}=I+(I-T)S_{n}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(c)**  Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}S_{n}T=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}TS_{n}=I$.

**(d)**  Note that $S-S_n=(I-T)^{n+1}S$

**(e)** This is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this by doing (e) first, then (d), then observing the right hand side of (d) $\to 0$.

(e) should be clear by definition. Then, by induction, we can show (d). Hints: (base case, use the reverse triangle inequality, inductive step use (e)).

I feel like this is the most natural way of doing these questions, since (c) is an easy consequence of (d) which is a straightforward consequence of (e).

Comment: Thanks both, 
I used my own methods and yours and @Aweygan